# Mat-Button routerLinkActive alternative?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to change my mat-button's color when clicked(which has mat-icon inside).`routerLinkActive="mat-accent"`(or whatever) doesn't work I don't know why I expected that should work.Do you have any suggestion?Here what I tried below

```
   <button style="margin-left:auto;"  mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="belowMenu"  routerLinkActive="mat-accent">
        <mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isFinishedSize>0" class="badge">{{isFinishedSize}}</span>
        <mat-menu class="myBorder" #belowMenu="matMenu">
            <h4 style="margin-left:17px;">Pending Tasks</h4>
            <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let not of notifications;">
                <li *ngIf="!not.isFinished" class="list-group-item">{{not.description}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button style="margin-left:5px;" routerLink="/notifications" mat-button><strong>See the
                    Details</strong>
                <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-menu>
    </button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to the button when the button is clicked.
Add this to the html:

```
(click)="btnClick('someId')" [class.active-btn]="activeId=='someId'"
```

add this to your .ts file

```
activeId = '';
btnClick(id: string) {
  this.activeId = id;
}
```

Then you can style the button as you'd like using css

```
.active-btn {
  color: orange;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

final html:

```
 <button style="margin-left:auto;"  mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="belowMenu"  routerLinkActive="mat-accent" (click)="btnClick('someId')" [class.active-btn]="activeId=='someId'">
        <mat-icon>notifications</mat-icon>
        <span *ngIf="isFinishedSize>0" class="badge">{{isFinishedSize}}</span>
        <mat-menu class="myBorder" #belowMenu="matMenu">
            <h4 style="margin-left:17px;">Pending Tasks</h4>
            <ul class="list-group" *ngFor="let not of notifications;">
                <li *ngIf="!not.isFinished" class="list-group-item">{{not.description}}</li>
            </ul>
            <button style="margin-left:5px;" routerLink="/notifications" mat-button><strong>See the
                    Details</strong>
                <mat-icon>arrow_forward_ios</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </mat-menu>
    </button>
```

Comment: That works man thanks!But how can I make it default color when its not clicked,at first button get clicked it turns orange forever now

Comment: Then, instead of using a string, `activeId`, use a map. E.g. `activeBtns = {}`. then, in the click-method, add the id to the map: `this.activeBtns[id] = true`. Then, you can check if there exists an entry from the html: `[class.activeBtn]="activeBtns['someId]"`

Comment: @TimuçinÇiçek I hope you can accept the answer if it solved your issue

Comment: yeah kinda solved.I improved your answer and achieved the answer I was looking for exactly.Thanks a lot !